# Checking if amount in subgroup is significant to population

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, binary-data

I have a population of known size N. For each element I can state whether an attribute is true or false. I can also divide the population into distinct sub populations.
Each sub population is of the same size.

I want to test whether the sub population with the most true attributes differs significantly from rest in terms of positive attributes (i.e., reject $H_0$: the sub population is not different). What statistical test do I have to apply?

My initial thought was the student's t-test but the [explanations](http://www.biostathandbook.com/onesamplettest.html) I found do not use binary outcomes of the measurement variable. Another possibility was to apply the 2sigma rule, however, I am not sure if it applies here.

Example:

```
Population  { A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3 }
Truth Value { 0,  0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 }
```

I now want to know if the amount of 0 values in sub population A is significantly different to the whole population (or remaining population). It can be assumed that each element of the population is statistically independent.

Comment: Presumably you are sampling randomly. But are the subpopulation identifiers observed or selected (stratified sampling)?  Are you sampling without or with replacement?  Do you know the value of $N$? Do you need to test more than one subpopulation?  In short, what aspect of your problem suggests a standard [two-sample test of proportions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=two-sample+test+of+proportions) would not apply?

Comment: @whuber I was not aware that this test exists. At a glance there is no reason against it. I am sampling without replacement, i.e., looking at the first n of each subpopulation. If by N you mean the size of the whole (sample) population, then yes. No I only want to test one (i.e., the population that has the most). Feel free yo post your comment as a response.

Comment: Could you tell us how you know which (sub)population "has the most"?  That is, do you wish to compare a prespecified subpopulation to the rest, or do you wish to determine whether the subpopulation that is most frequent in your sample is also more numerous in the population?  Or something else?

Comment: In my example I have the three sub populations A,B,C. I can count for each the the truth values. I.e., A=1,B=3,C=2. In this case I would want to test if B is significantly different. Each sub population is of the same size, i.e., the sampling stopped when I reached a predefined number.

Comment: Please include all that information in your question itself, because it *greatly* affects the answers!